# What is the way to change the color of the icon

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

What is the way to change the color of the icon to red if the condition is greater than 0 and if it is equal to zero then it will be gray

```
<TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => {
              if (Object.values(selectedItems).length > 0)
                navigation.navigate('total', {
                  selectedItems: Object.values(selectedItems),
                });
            }}
          >
            <Icon size={40} color="white" name="barrel" />
          </TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<Icon size={40} color={condition ? "red" : "gray"} name="barrel" />
```

should work